# Access SQL DATEDIFF greater than 7 days

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write out a query with Access SQL which will show results where the difference in days is beyond 7 (both 7 and -7)

I thought that this would work

```
SELECT DateDiff('d', EndDate1, EndDate2) > 7 AS EndDate
FROM TableName
```

However I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The query should return a boolean - `0` and `-1` in Access.  My test had no problem parsing the `>` symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put this in the `WHERE` statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ABS(DateDiff('d', EndDate1, EndDate2)) > 7
```

Comment: That would only return the dates with  +7 difference.  Wrap the `DateDiff` in `Abs` and it will return minus differences to.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Oh, haha. Thanks, forgot this.

Comment: You are welcome. Nice to hear that this helped you :)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to put conditional logic for selecting results in the actual `SELECT` however it actually belongs in the `WHERE` (if your intention is to filter records)

Now, if you wanted to identify records that were perhaps in/out of the date boundaries, you could always do something like:

```
SELECT iif(
          ABS(DateDiff('d', EndDate1, EndDate2)) > 7, 
          'out of bounds', 
           'in bounds'
          ) AS DateRangeStatus
```

I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to explain what's going on.